# Can the Google SMS Messenger app be launched without animation?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-animation

I am trying to launch the [Google's SMS Messenger app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en) from my activity without any animation. I tried adding the flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION while launching it. But still it launches with that default animation (my activity is pushed to the background and the new activity launches from bottom of the screen). I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here or it is a problem with the Messenger app itself, that it is not honoring that flag.

Code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:222222222"));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
```

Have also tried adding the below line after the activity was started, but doesn't help.

```
overridePendingTransition(0,0);
```

Comment: Show us the code you use

Comment: @Blundell - edited my question to add the code.